# Dynamically adding a static transformation to tf

Tags: ros, static-transform-publisher, roscpp, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have written an object in C++ which contains position and orientation information in member variables. These variables are not likely to change over the lifetime of the object. I am using these variables to perform my own hard-coded transforms between the world and the frame defined by each object.

I realize now that this is probably not the correct way to do things, and I should be using tf to do this work for me.

My question is how do I setup a static frame for each object when it is constructed?

I know I can create a static_transform_publisher node to do this, but I'm not too excited about creating a bunch of nodes during program operation that don't really do anything. It seems opposed to the ROS design philosophy.

Is there some object I can create that will do this for me?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/211891/dynamically-adding-a-static-transformation-to-tf/) by [Sebastian](https://answers.ros.org/users/22737/sebastian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 363 on 2015-06-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[multistatic_transform_publisher](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_tf_tools/blob/master/scripts/multi_static_transform_publisher.py) from [lscr_tf_tools](https://github.com/jhu-lcsr/lcsr_tf_tools) can help with this. You can run a single transform publisher node, and use messages to tell it to  set transforms.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2015-06-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2